# SQL Compute Cosine Similarity with Specific vector

Tags: mysql, sql, cosine-similarity

I have a `Item` and `Vector` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
  itemID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(256)
);

CREATE TABLE Vector (
  itemID INT REFERENCES Item(itemID),
  dim INT,
  value FLOAT
);
```

So for instance, if item 3 has vector `<4,2,5>` we have `(3, 0, 4), (3,1,2), (3,2,5)` in `Vector` table.  (In reality, it is not 3 dimensional, can be really big)

Now given specific vector `V=<v_1, v_2, v_3>`, I want to `SELECT` 10 `Item`s with smallest cosine distance to vector `V`.

I am struggling to find the way to send the vector `V` to the SQL Server.

Please help me!

---

I am using MySQL on Ubuntu

Comment: The data structure is not clear. for your example, please describe the data set - which table contains which rows

Comment: To send the vector, either insert it into a temporary table (or the same table if you add a column `temp`), or directly use it in your query, e.g. `select * from (select 0 as dim, v_1 as value union select 1, v_2 union select 2, v_3) as vec left join <your other tables> where <your calculation>` (`v_x` being the actual values). If you want to pass the vector to a procedure, you can pass it as a varchar (e.g. `$v1+','+$v2+','+$v3+...`) and split it again using `substring_index`. I'm glad that that's the only part you are struggling with, because the rest is the way harder part of this problem.